# The named parameter isn't defined (data persistence)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

There is my error , I want to solve this problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtPYF.png)
The named parameter 'itemCount' isn't defined.
The named parameter 'itemBuilder' isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default constructor that has different named parameters, you need to use `ListView.builder()` to use those named arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Syed i might thing that your try to use Listview() on Place of Listview.builder()....

```
      ListView(
        children: [
          Container(),
        ],
      ),
      
      ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Container();
          }
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ListView()` don't have thies properties but a `ListView.builder()` have they.

list view have `children` and not `itembuilder`.